# Segmentation Fault In My Xlib Wrapper Class (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, xlib, x11

I am attempting to create a wrapper class to the Xlib library, but I get a segmentation fault! I am new to C++ and this is probably out of my depth and maybe have my goals set to high, other than that problem, can someone tell my why I'm getting this segmentation fault?
[source file](http://pastebin.com/LRah1UpT)
[header file](http://pastebin.com/Um7RC3PN)
[main.cpp](http://pastebin.com/RXKQauwp)

I believe this is the back trace I get:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In XMapWindow () (/usr/lib/libX11.so.6)
At /home/elliot/Programming/C and C++/XWindows/src/MyWindow.cpp:49
```

Comment: Please don't use pastebin and derivates on this site. Try to get a backtrace, it helps a lot to locate the problem. You can do this by compiling your program with debug enabled (`-g` option when using g++) and then run it in a debugger (for example `gdb a.out` then type `run` and after it crashed `bt` to get the backtrace).

Comment: IMHO, pastebin is fine - the code is too long to copy&paste here.

Comment: Hi Ell, I am a beginner and need more imformation about wrap Xlib by C++. Like the simple example here. Where to get it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error indicates that either the `display` or `window` parameters to `XMapWindow()` were incorrect.

You need to include more error checking in your code, in particular for the results of the calls to `XOpenDisplay` and `XCreateWindow`.

The only obvious error I can see is that you're passing the `CWBackPixel` flag to `XCreateWindow` but have left the `attributes` parameter uninitialised.  Unlike plain C, C++ does not clear the memory contents of structures when they're declared.

**EDIT** - I of course missed the really blindingly obvious error - you've inadvertently redeclared all of your classes member variables within your constructor.  That'll be your scope problem.  You need to remove the typenames from all of the assignments within the constructor, e.g.:

```
MyWindow::MyWindow()
{   //ctor
    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    visual = XDefaultVisual(display, 0);
    depth = XDefaultDepth(display, 0);
    window = XCreateWindow(display, XRootWindow(display, 0), 0, 0, MyWindow::default_width, MyWindow::default_height, 16, depth, InputOutput, visual, CWBackPixel, &attributes);
    XStoreName(display, window, MyWindow::default_caption.c_str());
    XSelectInput(display, window, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, if I move the XMapWindow(display, window) and the whole loop function to the constructor, it seems to work fine, so maybe this is a really stupid mistake from me about variable scope?

Comment: Thank you so much! You really have made my day! I was just about to give up! :D